# Calculations from fields in another section in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

What is the proper syntax for calling fields outside the current section for the calculation fields?

Comment: I am a developer for Cognito Forms. Currently no syntax is available to call to a field outside of a section. Where are the fields located in relation to one another?

Comment: To add to the comment by @NicholasGasque, you can reference fields in child sections using syntax like `ChildSection.Field`, but cannot access fields in parent sections (and therefore not sibling sections). What syntax do you think would make sense for this?  We have been considering adding a Parent property to represent the parent section, but have held off because we were concerned it would be too confusing for most users.  In this case accessing a field in a sibling section would look like `Parent.SiblingSection.Field`.

Comment: I was simply using sections (perhaps incorrectly) to group fields visually. And, I was wanting to have some calculation fields in a summary section that referenced fields in different (sibling or parent) sections. Since the sections were only being used for visual grouping, I just removed them and put all of the fields together.

Comment: As long as your summary fields are not in a section, you can still have your other fields in sections for visual grouping, as calculations can reference fields in "child" sections, just not "siblings".  Glad you were able to figure out a workaround for your case!

Answer (score 1):

You can now write calculations within sections in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) that reference other sections or the parent form.

Simply type `Form.` within calculations to access fields and sections at the form level while writing calculations inside a section.  Also, when writing calculations inside a section which is inside a repeating section, you can use `ParentSection.` to access the parent repeating section item.

Please check out our help documentation for more information:
https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/2/calculations